# Data truncated for column when using FLOAT in GUI

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, floating-point, truncated

I am using a video course on database programming with the current lesson being using Java to connect to MySQL. I have followed the video, and even copied the text working file for this particular problem (so I know the code works), but I am still getting an error. The database is to store information for books: isbn, title, author, publisher, and price. I inserted the exact same data using the command line, but when I use the program for a GUI I get a "data truncated" error. I know there are multiple answers in "data truncated" errors; however, I do not see where the data is too large, especially when inserting works using a non GUI interface. All datatypes are VARCHAR except for price which is FLOAT. The error I get is:

insert into book values('978007106789','Stuck On Java','J Reid','9.99','Osborne')
Error executing SQL
java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'price' at row 1

GUI code is:

```
package Connection;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class InsertRecord extends JFrame {
   private JButton getBookButton, insertBookButton;
   private JList bookList;
   private Connection connection;
   private JTextField isbn, title, author, price, publisher;
   private JTextArea errorText;

   public InsertRecord() {
      try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      } 
      catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println("Unable to load driver.");
         System.exit(1);
      }
   }

   public void loadBook() {
      Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
      try {
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select title from book");
         while (rs.next()) {
            v.addElement(rs.getString("title"));
         }
         rs.close();
      }
      catch (SQLException e) {
         System.err.println("Error executing SQL");
      }
      bookList.setListData(v);
   }

   private void createGUI() {
      Container c = getContentPane();
      c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      bookList = new JList();
      loadBook();
      bookList.setVisibleRowCount(2);
      JScrollPane bookListScrollPane = new JScrollPane(bookList);

      getBookButton = new JButton("Get Book Title");
      getBookButton.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               String query = "select * from book where title = " + 
                      bookList.getSelectedValue();
               try {
                  Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

                  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(
                     "select * from book where title = '"
                     + bookList.getSelectedValue() + "'");
          /*ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(
                    "select * from book where title = 'Java:How To Program'");  */
                  if (rs.next()) {
                     isbn.setText(rs.getString("isbn"));
                     title.setText(rs.getString("title"));
                     author.setText(rs.getString("author"));
                     price.setText(rs.getString("price"));
                     publisher.setText(rs.getString("publisher"));
                  }
                } 
                catch (SQLException ex) { isbn.setText(query); }
            }
         }
      );

      insertBookButton = new JButton("Insert Book");
      insertBookButton.addActionListener (
         new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               try {
                  Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                  String insert = "insert into book values(";
                     insert += "'" + isbn.getText() + "',";
                     insert += "'" + title.getText() + "',";
                     insert += "'" + author.getText() + "',";
                     insert += "'" + price.getText() + "',";
                     insert += "'" + publisher.getText() + "')";
                  System.out.println(insert);
                  /*int i = statement.executeUpdate("insert into book values(" + 
                     "'" + isbn.getText() + "'," + 
                     "'" + title.getText() + "'," + 
                     "'" + author.getText() + "'," + 
                     "'" + price.getText() + "'," + 
                     "'" + publisher.getText() + ")");*/
                  int i = statement.executeUpdate(insert);
                  errorText.append("Inserted " + i + " rows succcessfully.");
                  bookList.removeAll();
                  loadBook();
                }
                catch (SQLException ex) {
                   System.err.println("Error executing SQL");
                   ex.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
          }
      );

      JPanel first = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
      first.add(bookListScrollPane);
      first.add(getBookButton);
      first.add(insertBookButton);

      isbn = new JTextField(13);
      title = new JTextField(50);
      author = new JTextField(50);
      price = new JTextField(8);
      publisher = new JTextField(50);
      errorText = new JTextArea(5,15);
      errorText.setEditable(false);

      JPanel second = new JPanel();
      second.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
      second.add(isbn);
      second.add(title);
      second.add(author);
      second.add(price);
      second.add(publisher);

      JPanel third = new JPanel();
      third.add(new JScrollPane(errorText));

      c.add(first);
      c.add(second);
      c.add(third);
      setSize(800, 400);
      setVisible(true);
   }

   public void connectToDB() throws Exception {
     //Connection conn = null;
      try {
         String userName = "jesse";
         String password = "password";
         String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/library";
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
         //if (conn != null) System.out.println("Database connection successful.");
      }
      catch (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println("Can't connect to database");
         System.exit(1);
      }
   }

   private void init() throws Exception{
      connectToDB();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      InsertRecord insert = new InsertRecord();

      insert.addWindowListener(
         new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
               System.exit(0);
            }
         }
      );

      insert.init();
      insert.createGUI();
   }
}
```

The insert code for simply using the command line is:

```
package Connection;

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class InsertDB {

    Connection connection;

    public InsertDB(){

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not load driver.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   


    public void ConnectToDB() {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/library", "jesse", "password");
            System.out.println("Connected to database.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot connect to database.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void execSQL() {
        try {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter the isbn: ");
            String isbn = input.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the title: ");
            String title = input.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the author: ");
            String author = input.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the publisher: ");
            String pub = input.readLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the price: ");
            String p = input.readLine();
            double price = Double.parseDouble(p);


            String insert = "Insert into book values (" + "'" + isbn + "','" + title + "','" + author + "','" + pub + "'," + price + ")";
            System.out.println(insert);
            int inserted = stmt.executeUpdate(insert); //returns 1 for success, 0 for failure
            if (inserted > 0) {
                System.out.println("Successfully inserted " + inserted + " row.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error executing SQL");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        InsertDB conn = new InsertDB();
        conn.ConnectToDB();
        conn.execSQL();
    }
}
```

The only differences I have noticed is price being in quotes in the GUI code; however, removing the quotes simply causes the same error without quotes. Also I noticed that the GUI code sets price to 8 bits (original code was 10), whereas, float is not set to anything in MySQL (I believe I read on another post it is 8 bits by default... which is why I used 8). I reached out to the author of the video and he suggested I remove the quotes surrounding price. But as I stated this did not help... also this code was copied from his working file that worked on the video. Any help is appreciated.

Database code is:

```
drop table book;

create table book (
    isbn_13 varchar(13) primary key,
    title varchar(50),
    author varchar(50),
    publisher varchar(50),  
    price float(11)
);
```

Comment: Can you please also include the code you are using the create the table?

Comment: drop table book;

create table book (
 isbn_13 varchar(13) primary key,
 title varchar(50),
 author varchar(50),
 publisher varchar(50), 
    price float(11)
);

Comment: When you initialize the text fields use the parameterless constructor. When reading from the GUI, instead of `isbn.getText()` use `isbn.getText().trim()`. This should remove unnecessary white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Starting again from scratch I completely dropped the book table then recreated it using the MySQL code above. After recreating the table I was able to insert using the GUI code. I am not sure what the cause of my problem was, but dropping and recreating the table seemed to fix it.